# R Packages for Limnology

Tags: r, package

I am wondering if anyone knows of an R package to aid to common limnological calculations.   I am specifically interested in calculating the position of the thermocline, sizes of the epi, meta, and hypolimnions, thermal stability, etc.  I have found the "wq" package which deals with water quality monitoring data on a temporal scale, probably more applicable to lotic (streams, rivers) than lentic (lakes, ponds) systems.  I recall coming across something about two years ago which ran these functions through R but at the time I was not familiar with R so passed it up.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that, even amongst the things I still need to add to the task view @JD Long mentions. Have a search on r-forge.r-project.org for anything I may have missed. If you fancy collaborating on a package to implement these things, I'd be happy to contribute.

Comment: The wq package has been archived but it is now revived as [wql](https://cran.r-project.org/package=wql)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like [AquaEnv](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=284) will do all of the things you mentioned (indeed, those are pretty much core functions of this Package.

i don't believe this package is available on CRAN, rather it's on R-Forge; hence, you can download and install it by:

```
install.packages("AquaEnv", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

The most recent version (available on R-Forge) was released in 2010-04-09.

I Have used it for simulation work (though it's not a general simulation package) and i was impressed with the numerical stability and with the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is so far out of my field I can't even see my field from where you are. But if such a package did exist, I bet it would be in the [CRAN Environmetrics task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Environmetrics.html).

For these sort of things I generally search Google with the [term I'm interested in + CRAN](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=limnological+CRAN&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). If that gives me nothing, I hop over to [rseek.org](http://rseek.org).

Good luck!

Comment: given the fact that he found the only relevant package I know of, I'm quite certain the OP has been there and done that...

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a limnology package *per se*, there is an oceanography package called "oce" that might have some of the functionality you are looking for with regard to things like processing CTD data.

Here's a link to the vignette..
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oce/vignettes/oce.pdf